# Crashlytics to Fabric, duplicate library projects

Tags: android, eclipse, crashlytics

So, a week or so ago we switched from Crittercism to Crashlytics, for various reasons.  It came with a plugin for Eclipse that automated some of the process.  Kinda convenient, sure, I guess.  But yesterday another developer in the company pulled the code and installed the plugin, and we discover they've changed it to Fabric, with Crashlytics becoming a part of Fabric, apparently.  Still fine, sure.  I figure, "I'll update my plugin to match his."  Here's where things go wrong.  The plugin installs fine, and I get things set up again - but now whenever I start Eclipse, it adds another set of duplicate libraries.  After restarting eclipse 4 times, for instance, I get:

[image]

...

[image]

I've deleted them multiple times, tampered with project.properties, searched for any references to the libraries that might be going astray, reset to working builds...no beans.  Every time I restart eclipse, it deletes most of the stuff from inside the existing library projects and creates new ones.  Anybody know what's up?

Comment: I have the opposite problem, I deleted them once and now I don't know how to get them back. They don't get re-created after restarting eclipse in my case so the compiler yells crashlytics import.

This is rather bad example of automated process.

Comment: @anoniim Hmm.  Have you deleted their actual project directories?  I think I may have done that sometimes to fix that; I don't remember.  Like, and then start Eclipse again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug in Fabric/Crashlytics; I emailed them and they fixed it in a day or two.  It no longer creates unnecessary copies of the projects.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, posting the steps I followed in case anyone finds it useful.

1. Download the Fabric app and login into it
2. Remove or comment out any Crashlytics or Fabric code you might have
3. Add a new app from the Fabric app, even though my app was already in the system and already had crashlytics installed, I had to add it again
4. Follow all the steps and it should work.